# Programmatically created UITablevIew changing its UITextField position while scrolling - iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have created `UITableView` Programmatically and on top of that i have `UITableVIewCell` with `UITextField` and `UILabel` (marked as green circle in attached image). When i scroll `UITableView` i can see my hidden part of `UITableViewCell` (bottom cells) and `UITextField` position is changed (marked as red circle in Attached image .

Please tell me how can i make sure all controls in `UITableViewCell` will be correctly aligned ??

> Green circle is correct and Red circle is wrong.

My code

```
    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath      *)indexPath;
{

    return 100;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     return [selectedTabFields count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"cell";
    NSLog(@"%@",[selectedTabFields objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
    cell= [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[homeCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                           reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }


    //cell.textLabel.text = @"My Text";
    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:[self getLabel:indexPath.row]];

    if([[[selectedTabFields valueForKey:@"type"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"VARCHAR"]){

        [cell.contentView addSubview:[self getVarcharTextfield:indexPath.row]];
    }else if([[[selectedTabFields valueForKey:@"type"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"INTEGER"]){
        [cell.contentView addSubview:[self getIntegerTextfield:indexPath.row]];

    }

    return cell;
}

-(UILabel *)getLabel:(NSUInteger)index{

    UILabel *slogan= [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,0,cell.frame.size.width,cell.frame.size.height)];
    //slogan.text=[[selectedTabFields valueForKey:@"name"] objectAtIndex:index];

    slogan.text=@"text Label";
    slogan.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
    slogan.font= [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Neue Light" size:12];
    slogan.font=[slogan.font fontWithSize:12];
    slogan.textColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
    slogan.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    return slogan;
}

//Varchar Textfield
-(UITextField *)getVarcharTextfield:(NSUInteger)index{

    UITextField *textField= [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,40,cell.frame.size.width-30,cell.frame.size.height)];
    textField.placeholder=@"Text here";
    textField.tag=index;
    textField.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
    textField.font= [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Neue Light" size:14];
    textField.textColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];
    textField.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:245.0/255.0 green:245.0/255.0 blue:245.0/255.0 alpha:1];
    return textField;
}


//Integer Textfield
-(UITextField *)getIntegerTextfield:(NSUInteger)index{

    UITextField *textField= [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,40,cell.frame.size.width-30,cell.frame.size.height)];
    textField.placeholder=@"Text here";
    textField.tag=index;
    textField.keyboardType=UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    textField.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentLeft;
    textField.font= [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Neue Light" size:14];
    textField.textColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];
    textField.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:245.0/255.0 green:245.0/255.0 blue:245.0/255.0 alpha:1];
    return textField;
}
```

Screenshot

[image: TableView screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cell is not nil when returned from `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`, that means it is an existing cell being reused. Your code that adds subviews and any other initialization that you want to do only once to a newly created cell should be inside the `if (cell == nil) {` section.

Also, you shoud consider having a different cell reuse type for your two differnt cell types, and add those subviews only to a newly created cell as well. So have `@"IntCell"` and `@"CharCell"`

Based on your code above:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier;
    if([[[selectedTabFields valueForKey:@"type"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"VARCHAR"]){
        MyIdentifier = @"CharCell";
    } else if([[[selectedTabFields valueForKey:@"type"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"INTEGER"]){
        MyIdentifier = @"IntCell";
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",[selectedTabFields objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
    cell= [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[homeCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                           reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
        //cell.textLabel.text = @"My Text";
        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:[self getLabel:indexPath.row]];

        if([[[selectedTabFields valueForKey:@"type"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"VARCHAR"]){

            [cell.contentView addSubview:[self getVarcharTextfield:indexPath.row]];
        }else if([[[selectedTabFields valueForKey:@"type"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"INTEGER"]){
            [cell.contentView addSubview:[self getIntegerTextfield:indexPath.row]];
        }
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove your subviews at the time of scrolling because it will keep on adding every time `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called.

```
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[homeCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                           reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

//cell.textLabel.text = @"My Text";
    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:[self getLabel:indexPath.row]];

    if([[[selectedTabFields valueForKey:@"type"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"VARCHAR"]){

        [cell.contentView addSubview:[self getVarcharTextfield:indexPath.row]];
    }else if([[[selectedTabFields valueForKey:@"type"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"INTEGER"]){
        [cell.contentView addSubview:[self getIntegerTextfield:indexPath.row]];

    }

}
else 
{
   [[[cell contentView] subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
}


    return cell;
```

Comment: you have to move the  entire controls to cell==nil if condition part.then only your code works

Comment: @Bangalore sorry, missed out the braces!!